# find and replace only complete term php preg_replace

Tags: php

I am trying to search and replace into a string, 
I have 2 problems
1. i need to check if term is inside a tag "term" - and do nothing in this case.
2. I need to make sure I am replacing a complte word and not cutting this word:

```
function str_replace_first($from, $to, $content)
{
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';

    return preg_replace($from, $to, $content, 1);
}
```

example:

```
echo str_replace_first('good','bad','goodmorning');
```

the result: badmorning // I need the script not to replace if we are cutting a word, and do the replace if we are changing a whole word
thanks

Comment: `'/^'.preg_quote($from, '/').'$/'`

Comment: @Nimer Can we get some sample data and expected results?  Please edit/improve your question.

Comment: @AbraCadaver what is that?

Comment: i think you will have to do it character-by-character and not use a regex for that as it does not have these requirements

Comment: [quietly wishing I could downvote @Nikos untrue comment]

Comment: whenever you see an open tag `<` mark it until closed, then replace the text and wait untill you see a close tag `<\`

Comment: @mickmackusa a regex cannot match tags and what is inside in a consistent manner. This is a requirement of the OP. Of course if the text is only as simple as the example posted then yes it is possible

Comment: @NikosM. Please avoid _trying_ to post solutions as comments.  Comments are to seek improvements or ask for clarifications.

Comment: @NikosM. Can regex be used: Yes.  Should it be used in this case? We don't know because we don't have any input data.  Rather than rush to a judgment, let's wait for clarification.

Comment: Quitely agreeing with @mickmackusa last comment

Comment: @Nimer Are we dealing with well-formed html here?  Or is this something unpredictable like user-supplied text?  Can you show us a few different examples of what the input can be and what you expect to output?

Comment: How close does this get you? [Regex to match words or phrases in string but NOT match if part of a URL or inside <a> </a> tags. php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6009415/2943403)  ...seems pretty close to me.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the script not to replace if we are cutting a word, and do the replace if we are changing a whole word

Luckily, the regular expression syntax has exactly what you need in the form of the `\b` word boundary marker. Simply add this to either end of the word you want to match, like so:

```
function str_replace_first($from, $to, $content)
{
    $from = '/\b'.preg_quote($from, '/').'\b/';

    return preg_replace($from, $to, $content, 1);
}
```

Now, the "good" in `goodmorning` will not be replaced, but `good morning` will be.